# Not able to create private directory on External storage using getExternalFilesDir() method

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I'm trying to make private directory on SD card by this code,

```
 if(Util.isExternalStorageWritable()) {

        int writePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int readPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (writePermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && readPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            File folder = new File(AddWazaif.this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "directory");
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdirs();
            }
        }
}
```

but directory not created. Directory created only with this method `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. but i want to only private directory so when app going to uninstall directory also gets delete. Please help.

> Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Directory Structure:
[image]

Comment: you also need to make sure you are handling the runtime permissions

Comment: @vikaskumar i implemented run time permission but still not created. please see my updated question

Comment: please see directory structure on my updated question. @JyotiJK

Comment: try `new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: @JyotiJK No way

Comment: @Zohaib what do you mean no way. did you get any error/ exception or warning

Comment: directory not created with your code

Comment: Sorry for incorrect statement about getExternalFilesDir() . the path is `/Android/data/yourapp/files/... `  .Please check it again in this path

Comment: this files/ path is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170198/discussion-between-zohaib-and-jyoti-jk).